# Does Feuter regularity imply derivability in all directions?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, quaternions, clifford-algebras

The standard type of regularity in [Clifford Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_analysis) is the one introduced by Feuter, namely:

> a function is Feuter regular iff it is in the zero set of the Clifford-Dirac
>
> operator $D= \partial x_0 + \sum e_i \partial x_i$
>
> where the $e_i$ are the orthonormal basis of vectors, bivectors, $\ldots$ of the algebra

Now, onto my question. In the case of the Clifford algebra $Cl(0, 1)$, aka the complex numbers, Feuter regularity at a point  plus suitable differentiability  in its neighborhood implies the existence and uniqueness of the derivative in all directions.

Is this true in a general Clifford algebra? I suspect not (*).

In that case, what goes wrong in  generalizing the standard proof there (by that I mean the usual proof in complex analysis books, such as the one reported by the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations) using the decomposition via the Wirtinger derivatives)? What else can be done to ensure that the derivative in all directions exists and it is unique?

(*) actually, I am pretty certain. In the quaternions, aka $Cl(0, 2)$, the usual naive version of derivative is satisfied only by a trivial class of functions (namely the linear ones), whereas there are tons of Feuter regular functions there.

Comment: I can't really comment on the general case of Clifford analysis, but I can say as much. The special case of bicomplex numbers works out just like the complex case, but that's because it too is a special case among the Clifford algebras by being commutative. In general, from the POV of associative algebras, you need the derivative/Jacobian to be in the center of the algebra. If the algebra has a trivial center, well you get the trivial class of functions (dep. on the field). I don't see a way out in the real case (maybe weakly?). OTH, in the complex case you have automatic joint holomorphy..

Comment: @July, can you provide some intuition as to why the Jacobian should be in the center of the algebra? Do you have some useful refs?

Comment: Is'nt it Fueter https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudolf_Fueter

Comment: @Mirco Mannucci: If $A$ is a finite-dim. associative algebra over the real or complex numbers and $f:A\to A$ is $A$-differentiable (also called $A$-holomorphic) in a neighbourhood of $z_0\in A$, then $f'(z_0)\in A$ gives an $A$-linear map $A\to A$ via the algebra multiplication. (Translated into a concrete matrix representation, you get the Jacobian or a transpose of it as well as generalized CR-equations.) Some key words: $A$-holomorphy, $A$-analyticity, $A$-differentiability, hypercomplex analysis, paracomplex geometry, hyperholomorphic functions...

Comment: (cont) There is actually tons of literature that remains rather obscured for some reason. The whole story starts with Sheffer in 19th century, and many took over his ideas to generalize complex analysis. In fact, Clifford Analysis was invented partially to remedy the bad behavior in case of noncommutative algebras by dropping certain part of the generalized CR-equations. There is the Kazan school: Shirokov, Shurygin, Vishnevskii, Shpakivskyi, Gaisin, Rosenfeld, Plaksa, Krasnov on the one hand. On the other hand, following Sheffer, there are papers of Fox, Ketchum, Kristzen, Hausdorff, Zorn...

Comment: (cont.) ...Ward, Graves, Snyder, Szekeres, Rinehart, Ringleb. For the hypercomplex side, you should check out the work of Sabadini, Strupa, Gadea, Masque, Delanghe, Kraußhar, Brackx, Price, Pogorui. Sorry for dumping so many names, but they've all worked or are working on variations and iterations of the above framework really and it's probably an overkill quantity of information for your question. I'll need to sort through my sources to find something specific for what you need, but I'm afraid my POV may not be so suitable for your purpose.

Comment: @July: thanks for the refs. I do not know many of them, but I do know some of the recent works by Sabadini, Gentili and Struppa, and somehow I have not seen anywhere a direct answer to the above. But perhaps I have missed something....